# Forgot to send checklist with UK Visa Application

Tags: visas, uk, applications, vfs-global, services

I have sent my documents without the checklist in it to VFS Services USA Inc. Also, I did not sign the application form. What may happen? Has anyone gone through a similar situation?

Edit:

- I have done biometrics already.
- The checklist has the instructions about a signature but no mention to include it anywhere when sending.
- The application form itself has no signature column to capture a signature.

Update on 03/Apr/19:
Received my passports in courier with approved UK stamp on it. 
Based on this experience, it is important to make sure that your financial support and other supporting documents are in acceptable state.

After your fingerprints appointment 1) there is no need to sign on the application form and 2) also per the comments the checklist is for reference only, don't need to submit as a supporting document.

Comment: Was this after providing biometrics? I suspect without a signature the application may be rejected (not refused) as invalid.

Comment: @Traveller I guess "rejected" is almost the same as if you had never sent the application, except you may lose some fees? So no negative consequences?

Answer (score 4):

The Document Checklist that is produced as part of completing the online application for a U.K. Standard Visitor visa requires a signature, and states that it should not be signed until the applicant is at the appointment. It also includes a space for the Submission Officer to sign. My understanding is that it is part of the required documents; if it wasn’t signed and submitted the application is incomplete and is likely to be rejected, unless the ECO decides to contact the applicant to ask for it.

Rejection is not the same as refusal.