# Applying for UK Visa from USA (CA)

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

Help! I'm so confused and I can't seem to find the answers anywhere. I am applying for a UK visa, I have Green Card in the US. I've completed:

- application online
- paid the fee
- got my biometrics done
- mailed my application and provided a return envelope

Questions:

1. Do I still need to make a separate appt at a London embassy – to go
   over the paper work?
2. Stupid me didn't notice that the document checklist needed a
   signature at the bottom of the page. It says someone at the appt
   will review the supporting documents but the biometric appt center I
   went to didn't have a service like that so what now?
3. Is there a way for me to submit additional documentation after I've
   already sent everything?
4. Can someone please (PLEASE) tell me what the process is for applying
   for a UK visa?

Has anyone had similar experiences?

Comment: Point 4: you seem to have followed the process. What specifically do you expect us to add?

Comment: Did you get the visa approved?

Answer (score 3):

Your document checklist doesn't need a signature when you apply from the USA, and you don't even need to include it with your visa application at all. You may still receive a visa, [as this person did](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/134020/3221).

There is a special process for [applying for a UK visa in the USA](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa). Unlike in many other countries, there is no appointment to visit to a VFS office to submit your documents and have them checked. (The biometrics appointment *only* takes biometrics and handles nothing else with respect to your visa application. They cannot even look at your visa documents.)

If the only thing you've forgotten is the signature on the document checklist, then you do not need to worry. Your visa will not be refused because the signature -- or the checklist! -- was missing. If you forgot other important documents, such as your bank statements, then you may want to withdraw your application and reapply.